# Alternative feature selection strategies

Tags: regression, correlation, p-value, feature-selection, scikit-learn

Which is a better strategy for curating an optimal set of features: choosing the ones having high correlation with the target variable, or choosing the ones whose coefficients' p-value is less than 0.05?

For some reason the latter is not included in `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`, unlike in `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS`, suggesting that it is not as good.

Comment: Neither.  Explore our higher-voted threads on feature selection to learn more.

Comment: I personally have found that a "leave one out" strategy can often be effective, where I start with all predictors and calculate fit statistics such as RMSE and R-squared. Then I repeatedly run the regression, each time leaving out one of the predictor variables, and observing the effect on the fit statistics. Finally when dropping any of the remaining predictors has a large noticeable effect on the fit statistics I am done. This does not always work, but is easy to program and runs quickly so long as I am use standard linear regression.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these are particularly useful.

First, "optimal" is poorly defined in this setting.  Shoe size *may* be a good predictor of (in so far as it correlates will with) appetite, but the knowing someone's shoe size has nothing to tell us about the causal mechanisms of hunger.  So in one sense shoe size may be part of an "optimal set" of predictors, but in others it is far from optimal.

On selection procedures with respect to p values, this is also a bad idea.  I can construct a model in which the p-value for a variable is highly significant, but the predictions from a model with/without the variable differ negligibly in predictive capabilities.

As whuber has noted, there are dozens of threads on this topic.  There is more information there than I can include in this answer.  Suffice it to say, both are bad options.